# Angular 4 startup performance

Tags: performance, angular, angular-compiler-cli

We have Angular 4 project compiled aot and bundled with rollup and without lazy loading. It takes about 3 seconds for scripting during startup. I need to reduce this time. I found examples of Angular 4 app with startup time less then 1 sec: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/bundling-demo-rollup#/demo/spreadsheet. So I believe it's possible to reduce our startup time. Below trace from our app.
[image: trace]

Some function calls are suspicious: build, compileComponent and _compileTemplate. This is aot compilation and still building and compilation at startup. I didn't find any useful information about it. Any suggestion about how could it happened or why it's correct are welcome.

Any suggestions on how to improve startup loading time are welcome as well.

**UPD**

Below sources tab
[image]

tsconfig-rollup.json

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "files": [
        "temp/app/main.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "temp/aot",
        "skipMetadataEmit": true
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2015",
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ]
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that it is AOT? `_compileTemplate` function is located in `@angular/compiler`. More precisely it is part of `JitCompiler`

Comment: Can you show us screenshot of `Sources` tab in devtools?

Comment: @yurzui it compiled with ngc by command `node node_modules\\@angular\\compiler-cli\\src\\main.js -p tsconfig-rollup.json --locale=en-US` for win machines and `./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-rollup.json --locale=en-US` for mac. but this functions are really suspicious. I checked for any references to @angular/compiler in code and found only in dependencies section of package.json.

Comment: @yurzui sources tab screen added

Comment: Seems something is being created by using compiler. `ng://t`

Comment: Yes, your `angularSPA.js` script contains code from `@angular/compiler`

Comment: How does your `tsconfig-rollup.json` look like? Do you use `platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);`? Perhaps you use some library that uses `JitCompiler` internally

Comment: I use `
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MainModule).catch((error) => {
 alert(error);
 console.dir(error);
});`

going to add tsconfig now

Comment: `platformBrowserDynamic` is used for jit compilation.

Comment: You can take a look at my aot example that is based on angular tutorial https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/tree/master/systemjs-ngc-rollup For production build i use https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/blob/master/systemjs-ngc-rollup/src/main-aot.ts#L9 See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: @yurzui many thanks to you! going to test it soon

Comment: You can always check your bundle `"check:aot": "source-map-explorer build-aot/build.js"`

Comment: @yurzui may you please answer question? want to save solution for feature ramblers and give you credit for it